# Drag and drop - get all elements inside the droppable

Tags: jquery, html, css

get all elements inside the droppable

Example: if I drag to the ten elements to droppable and remove three, when the click on the button gives it to identify the elements that are within the droppable.
Anyone know how to do this? I think other people face this problem.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could be worded better and you could show some code so we could help out out better.

Without knowing how your setup is, I would guess something like

```
$('#dropped-container .draggable-items').each(function() {
    $(this).whateverYouWantToDo();
});
```